# MySQL Select the rows having same column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to obtain the rows which having same column value from the following table, I tried it the following way, but it gives me a single row only.

```
select *
from employee e
group by e.empsalary
having count(e.empsalary) > 1
```

**Table employee**

[image]

Please suggest me a way.

Comment: `SELECT empsalary` and put it inside a nested query like `WHERE empsalary IN (SELECT empsalary ...)`

Comment: You can use SELF JOIN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by joining the table to itself:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    employee a
    JOIN employee b
        ON a.empsalary = b.empsalary
        AND a.empid != b.empid
```

Comment: Finally! This is what ive been looking for, for centuries! Thank you :D

Comment: @ZdeněkBednařík how do I check to match more than one column , not just empsalary but also say empaddress .

Answer (score 3):

Use an inner join to join with your query posted.

```
select A.* from employee A
inner join (
  select empsalary
  from employee 
  group by empsalary
  having count(*) > 1
) B ON A.empsalary = B.empsalary
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps

```
SELECT * FROM employee a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM employee b
    WHERE a.empsalary = b.empsalary
    AND a.empid <> b.empid
);
```

Demo - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d75d9/4

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from employee where empsalary IN(select empsalary from employee  group by empsalary having count(empsalary ) > 1)
```

Try This.It gives 2 rows as you want.

Demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d75d9/6